# In yolo Can I continue to training from final .weight with different class of images?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, image-classification, darknet, yolov4

I want to train a few products for image classification in **Yolo**. Let's say I have trained with 10 products (means 10 classes) and saved the best file. Now I want to **add some more data of other products** (means some new class names and images). So, can I call the previous trained model and then train again with only the new class of images? If not then **is there any way to retrain my model not from scratch but from the last trained file with new class of images.** Please, reply.

I have tried this code:

```
!python train.py --workers 8  --batch-size 16 --data products/data.yaml --img 640 640 --cfg cfg/training/yolov7_custom.yaml --epochs 5 --weights 'runs/train/products/weights/last.pt' --name yolov7_custom_newClass --hyp data/hyp.scratch.custom.yaml --device 0
```

Here, "**last.pt**" is the previous trained file, and "**data.yaml**" is the new data yaml file, whose number of classes is different as new images with new class names, after running the code, it show me this error:

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Model:
    size mismatch for model.105.m.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([30, 256, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([21, 256, 1, 1]).
    size mismatch for model.105.m.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([30]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([21]).
    size mismatch for model.105.m.1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([30, 512, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([21, 512, 1, 1]).
    size mismatch for model.105.m.1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([30]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([21]).
    size mismatch for model.105.m.2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([30, 1024, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([21, 1024, 1, 1]).
    size mismatch for model.105.m.2.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([30]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([21]).
    size mismatch for model.105.im.0.implicit: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1, 30, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1, 21, 1, 1]).
    size mismatch for model.105.im.1.implicit: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1, 30, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1, 21, 1, 1]).
    size mismatch for model.105.im.2.implicit: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1, 30, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1, 21, 1, 1]).
```

Looks like, as the new data.yaml file's number of classes are differnet from previous models, That's why this error occured.. Any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily freeze your weight by passing --freeze argument, try different number from small to big to get best results